# return just part of the bean with toJson()

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

I am trying to return `{"status": its value}`´in the case of `routeD!=0` currently I am getting `{"status":201,"routes":null}` I would get the response in this form `{"status":201}` without `"routes":null` at the same time I dont want to lost the response of `routeD==0` which is for example `{"status":230,"routes":[1,9,3]}`

I appeciate any help.

Receiver class:

```
@Path("/data")
public class Receiver {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response storeData(Data data) {
        Database db = new Database();

        String macD = data.getMac();
        int routeD = data.getRoute();
        double latD = data.getLatitude();
        double longD = data.getLongitude();
        double speedD = data.getSpeed();

        // Jackson class to wrapper the data in JSON string.
        SDBean bean = new SDBean();
        if (routeD != 0) {
            bean.status = db.insertData(macD, routeD, latD, longD);         
            return Response.status(bean.status).entity(bean.toJson()).build();

        } else {
            bean.routes = db.detectRoute(latD, longD);
            return Response.status(230).entity(bean.toJson()).build();

        }

    }

}
```

SDBean class:

```
public class SDBean {

    public int status;
    public ArrayList<Integer> routes;

    public SDBean(){
    status = 230;
}

    public String toJson() {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = null;
        try {
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
         System.out.println(json);
        return json;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.html)

> Annotation used to indicate when value of the annotated property (when used for a field, method or constructor parameter), or all properties of the annotated class, is to be serialized. Without annotation property values are always included, but by using this annotation one can specify simple exclusion rules to reduce amount of properties to write out.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
[...]

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class SDBean {
```